Redirect standard output to console in GUI application
I have a C++ application that I compile in GUI mode, and sometimes I run it from the console for debugging purpose. Since normally it doesn't write anything to the console, I attached the console and use freopen() to redirect standard output to the console using the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // Attach to the parent console
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)) {
        // Redirect stdout and stderr to the console
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    }
    std::cout << "print to stdout" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "print to stderr" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

However, I would like to do it using WinAPI directly instead of freopen().
I tried to use SetStdHandle() or following https://asawicki.info/news_1326_redirecting_standard_io_to_windows_console without luck, it prints nothing compared to freopen, which works.
In addition, when the program running the terminal doesn't detect well that it's currently running and if I press Enter, the terminal detects and shows me the prompt instead of sending it to the program. Can it be fixed as well?

IDK why someone wanted to add the java tag. It's not C code either.

@WeatherVane all forms of spamming have one reason - to drive more attention.

The article you are quoting doesn't use SetStdHandle.

I use the winapi functions AttachConsole() or AllocConsole() and then WriteConsole().

I prefer to use /subsystem:console in debug mode and /subsystem:windows in release. Although with that said I am writing Qt GUI applications and not directly winapi.

@WeatherVane , you should be more worried about how the java-tagging edit got approved. I see a good potential Audit in this one.

@user4581301 it wasn't approved, but a peer-review proposed edit, which I rejected.

@WeatherVane interesting. Edit history page reads like it was a full-on approved edit.  Timeline not any clearer on that front. If that's a bug, not worth fixing in the face of all the other stuff that needs a good working -over.


Long story short: do not try to reattach to a console.
But I need to see the standard output in the console.
Answer:
The bigger picture is that I have GUI application that I sometimes need to debug in production on users end.
It's actually Rust calling c++ bindings. I depend on c++ libraries that print errors info to standard output.
Using attach method I can see the errors from that libraries even in production simply by running the application from the console.


@user4581301 it looks as though it was approved in the same second that I rejected and replaced the edit, i.e. a fraction before.

@anonymous since you have things writing to the stdout object, it is not enough to just assign a new handle for the calling process with SetStdHandle(), you need  to use freopen() to re-initialize the stdout object so it actually uses the new handle.

@RemyLebeau
Does it possible to mimic freopen using WinAPI?

@anonymous no, because the stdout object is not part of the Win32 API, it belongs to the C runtime library. So, after you change the handle at the Win32 level, you need to update the C runtime library so it  knows about the new handle. The runtime library calls GetStdHandle() only once at startup, unless you tell it to update itself.

@RemyLebeau Thanks now it's much more clear.
How about mimic the whole behavior in WinAPI to achieve similar result?
I hope that at least this is possible with WinAPI

@anonymous to mimic what behavior, exactly?

Just freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); followed by std::ios::sync_with_stdio() will usually do. Some extra magic is required to make sure there are no redirects already ongoing, or you end up in bad places trying to re-bind to CONOUT$ as closing of the previous handles is going haywire. (So AllocConsole() is to be preferred over AttachConsole()).

@RemyLebeau
The program compiled in GUI mode (subsystem/windows)
So normally when I execute it from the console it doesn't show standard output.
I want to show that output if the program is running from the console (and AttachConsole succeed)

a lot of comments TL:DR,  my 2c : use a log file e.g. spdlog. you then got better control

@Ext3h
I did similar thing in the snippet attached here in the question.
I'm trying to do it without freopen() but with WinAPI instead or similar. Since I do it from Rust and I prefer not to use libc crates (library which is bindings to libc)

@AndersK
I don't have control over the c++ libraries I depend on and I need to get the standard output from them

"How about mimic the whole behavior in WinAPI to achieve similar result? I hope that at least this is possible with WinAPI" - Of course that's possible. You'll have to call WriteConsole (or WriteFile), though. You cannot use C or C++ I/O streams.

@anonymous You can't really do this without the libc runtime, you don't even get to know the handle associated with stdout without it, and you can't get around C++ runtime either as there isn't a backdoor for std::ios::sync_with_stdio() either. So whatever you are going to do, is still not going to work with existing 3rd party C++ libraries.

@llnspectable
See previous comment
"I don't have control over the c++ libraries I depend on and I need to get the standard output from them"

@anonymous then you are stuck using freopen() and sync_with_stdio so existing  Libraries will continue to operate properly and actually write to your new stdout.

@RemyLebeau
Why using SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, ...) with Console handle shouldn't work but freopen() works?

@anonymous As I already explained earlier, stdout/stderr are initialized once at startup. That means in your case, when they call GetStdHandle() during app statup, it will not return a valid handle for them to use since there is no console attached to the process yet. AFTER you call SetStdHandle() to assign a new handle, you need to re-initialize stdout/stderr with frepoen() so they will then call GetStdHandle() again to get the updated handle so they can start using it.

@RemyLebeau
I think I understand now. The c++ standard streams are managed internally by the c runtime library. SetStdHandle affects other WinAPI calls that use the handle, but not the c++ runtime's streams. That's why I need to use freopen() or similar functions from libc to change the c++ runtime streams.

@anonymous then maybe should added that in the question then - that you 3rd party libraries where you want this requested functionality.

Based on answers in comments:
The c++ standard streams are managed internally by the c runtime library. SetStdHandle affects other WinAPI calls that use the handle, but not the c++ runtime's streams. That's why I need to use freopen() or similar functions from libc to change the c++ runtime streams.

Too long for a comment, but I haven’t done this in ages and am unsure if I have missed anything. (Feel free to edit.)
There is absolutely nothing wrong with attaching a console to your GUI process on Windows. You just need to dot a few ‘i’s.
AttachConsole() is for connecting to an extant conhost process. If there is no existing parent process console, it will fail.
If you wish to simply open a console belonging only to you, use AllocConsole().
Both functions will fail if you are already attached to a console. Use FreeConsole() to disconnect first.
Once attached to a console, you must use some Win32 deep magic to properly associate the standard streams with that console. All the important magic is found in that console_init_c() routine. We are also careful not to drop any redirected streams, odd as it may be to start a GUI with redirected standard I/O.
(While the Q is tagged with C++, the following is C, so it works with both C and C++):
// Windows library code requires the following to
// be true in order to use the console functions.

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#elif _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0501
  #undef _WIN32_WINNT
  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus
  #include <iso646.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
#else
  #include <ciso646>
  #include <cstdio>
#endif


static bool is_console_redirected( DWORD id )
{
  HANDLE h = GetStdHandle( id );      // (the handle is redirected if)
  return (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  // the standard handle is already attached to something
      and (GetFileType( h ) != FILE_TYPE_CHAR);  // AND: file type is PIPE, DISK, etc
}


static bool console_init_c( DWORD id, FILE * stdfp, const char * mode )
{
  intptr_t h  = (intptr_t) GetStdHandle( id );
  int      fd = _open_osfhandle( h, _O_TEXT );  if (!fd)                 return false;
  FILE *   fp = _fdopen( fd, mode );            if (!fp) { _close( fd ); return false; }
  *stdfp = *fp;
  setvbuf( stdfp, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );  // stdin, stdout, and stderr are all unbuffered on Windows
  return true;
}


bool console_attach_pid( DWORD pid, bool is_detach_first )
//
// pid
//   0                      :: Attach to my own (new) console
//   ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS  :: Attach to the parent process's console
//   (some process's PID)   :: Attach to the given process's console
//
// is_detach_first
//   false  :: Returns true/success if the process is already attached
//             to any console, regardless of the value of `pid`.
//   true   :: Use this if you wish to attempt to _change_ a console
//             attachment from (for example) the parent's to a new one.
//
{
  // Are any of the standard streams currently attached to a redirected stream?

  bool is_stdin_redirected  = is_console_redirected( STD_INPUT_HANDLE  );
  bool is_stdout_redirected = is_console_redirected( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  bool is_stderr_redirected = is_console_redirected( STD_ERROR_HANDLE  );

  // Attempt to connect to the desired console host

  if (is_detach_first)
    FreeConsole();

  BOOL ok = pid
    ? AttachConsole( pid )
    : AllocConsole();

  if (!ok)
    switch (GetLastError())
    {
      // Already attached to a console
      case ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
        return true;

      // No parent; try to create a new console
      case ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE:
      case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
        if (!AllocConsole())
          return false;

      // All other errors
      default:
          return false;
    }

  // Now for the Windows magic that makes C I/O work
  // (Read the docs for why we don't need to worry about
  //  managing resources beyond what we have done here.)
  
  bool success =
    (is_stdin_redirected  or console_init_c( STD_INPUT_HANDLE,  stdin,  "rt" )) and
    (is_stdout_redirected or console_init_c( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, stdout, "wt" )) and
    (is_stderr_redirected or console_init_c( STD_ERROR_HANDLE,  stderr, "wt" ));

  if (!success)
    FreeConsole();
      
  return success;
}

I think some additional care (with dup() etc) might be necessary if you plan to play with the low file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 directly, but again, I am unsure (and don’t want to bother messing with it right now. Again, edit if you know better).
Please note that the code is technically UB — but it is how to do it on Windows.

I think some additional care (with dup() etc) might be necessary if you plan to play with the low file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 directly  ISTR something similar.  I also seem to remember that if you call close() on the fd or fclose() on fp, you'll find out why...

"the following is C, so it works with both C and C++" - I'm waiting for the language lawyers to school you that "C and C++ are very different languages", right after they've tarred and feathered and burnt you at the stake. Seriously, though, this is missing a lot of rationale, primarily how the language support runtime has to be in on the joke. This isn't "some deep Win32 magic". Indeed, the Win32 isn't involved in any of this.

@AndrewHenle Yes, the docs make it clear that you should not fclose() that stuff.

@IInspectable ??? Different languages that often intersect, as in this case. And _open_osfhandle() is most definitely Win32 magic.

Anything with a leading underscore is most certainly not a symbol in the Win32 API. Indeed, _open_osfhandle is declared in <io.h> (that delegates to <corecrt_io.h>), part of the Universal CRT. It is shipped as part of the OS but is concerned with C language support.

@Dúthomhas I'm also remembering that binary/text mode matters for both _open_osfhandle() and _fdopen().  I think the _O_TEXT in your call to _open_osfhandle( h, _O_TEXT ) could cause problems for binary streams.

@Dúthomhas
For simplicity in the examples I ignore error checking and redirection handling.
I commented out freopen and used console_init_c() instead but it doesn't work.
https://pastebin.com/cwjGf813
By the way according to replies in previous comments it's not possible without using freopen() which changes internal handle of libc

@AndrewHenle If it is attached to the console then it is a text stream. Only redirected stuff can be binary.

@anonymous The public function offered you is attach_console_pid(). If you just cut and paste pieces of it, and especially if you do not check error conditions, then something will likely go wrong.

@Dúthomhas
I don't see attach_console_pid() function. I can see console_attach_pid() but you didn't call it

Sorry, typo. I also did not define main(). The goal was not to rewrite your program, but to give you a little library function to use in your code.

@Dúthomhas
That's why I tried to replace freopen() as you can see in the link I added.
But for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe the state that it's not possible without freopen() is right
